# Proper way to pass arabaic parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
 <?php
   $tit = rawurldecode("نقفورالثاني-فوكاس");
   $cap = rawurldecode("الطريق-للقمة");
   ?>
   <a href = '<?php echo "road.php?title=$tit&caption=$cap" ; ?>'>
```

Is producing  weird % space characters, how can I properly send arabic parameters, it is becoming:

http://www.nikephorosphokas.com/%D9%86%D9%82%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%88%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%B3/%25D9%2586%25D9%2582%25D9%2581%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AB%25D8%25A7%25D9%2586%25D9%258A-%25D9%2581%25D9%2588%25D9%2583%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B3/%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B7%25D8%25B1%25D9%258A%25D9%2582-%25D9%2584%25D9%2584%25D9%2582%25D9%2585%25D8%25A9/

First Time is correct because of passing it through clean url, but second part is not working regardless of any method:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /road.php\?title=([^&\s]+)&caption=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . نقفورالثانيفوكاس/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=rawurldecode($1) [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=rawurldecode($1)&caption=rawurldecode($2) [QSA,L]
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question, but `rawurldecode` in .htaccess doesn't look right.

Comment: OK I can remove it, this si the issue
http://www.nikephorosphokas.com/
Clicking on road from index, the link is:

      <?php
 $tit = rawurldecode("نقفورالثاني-فوكاس");
 $cap = rawurldecode("الطريق-للقمة");
    ?>
   <a href = '<?php echo "road.php?title=$tit&caption=$cap" ; ?>'>

Clicking the link, the parameters up get ruined:

http://www.nikephorosphokas.com/%D9%86%D9%82%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%88%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%B3/%25D9%2586%25D9%2582%25D9%2581%25D9......

Instead of showing the arabic words

Comment: why weird % space characters? That's what rawurldecode does: replacing all non-alphanumeric signs into a % followed by two hex-values.

Moreover you cannot use a function such as rawurldecode in an url within a rewriterule in .htaccess

Comment: I tried the other waya rounf with encode, same result

Comment: <?php
      $tit = rawurlencode("نقفورالثاني-فوكاس");
      $cap = rawurlencode("الطريق-للقمة");
      ?>
Here and on .htaccess, same result

Comment: RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=rawurlencode($1) [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=rawurlencode($1)&caption=rawurlencode($2) [QSA,L]

And int he file

               <?php
      $tit = rawurlencode("نقفورالثاني-فوكاس");
      $cap = rawurlencode("الطريق-للقمة");
      ?>
               <a href = '<?php echo "road.php?title=$tit&caption=$cap" ; ?>'>

Same result